# AWS t1 to t2 migration: Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown on new t2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I've had a Linux t1.micro running a small Apache/PHP/Postgresql website for a couple of years now (referred herein as "original instance").  Works like a charm.

I wanted to migrate the site to the new (cheaper) t2.micro instance.  I couldn't find any step by step instructions for how to do this, but took note of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031710/how-to-change-the-instance-type-in-amazon-ec2) and [this](http://samrueby.com/2014/07/02/having-trouble-moving-from-aws-t1-micro-to-t2-mico-instances/).

My basic approach was

1. Create snapshots of the two volumes (root and a data drive for the postgresql data) used by the original instance
2. Create a new HVM AMI from the root and data snapshots just taken (ELASTIC BLOCK STORE > Snapshots > select original instance root snaphot > Actions > Create Image), with

   - Architecture = x86_64, same as the original instance
   - Root device and data volume device names = same as the original instance
   - Virtualization type = Hardware-assisted virtualization (HVM, for compatibility with the new t2 VM format)
   - Kernel ID = "Use default" (I tried to used the same Kernel ID as the original instance, but the AMI create failed saying it couldn't use that for a HVM AMI)
3. Create and launch a new instance with the AMI just created at step 2

Problem: upon starting this new instance, it shuts down immediately with a `Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown` error.  How can I troubleshoot this?

Am I naive to think I can use a root snapshot that works in a PVM environment in an HVM environment? Is there an easier way to migrate from t1 to t2?

I'm hoping not to have to re-build my server in t2 from scratch and migrate data manually (I didn't use any automated build scripts).

**Edit**:  I ended up rebuilding the t2 instance from scratch :P

Comment: I had a very similar problem recently, but it was with volume types instead of instance families. I was attempting to create a new instance with the new "gp2" type SSD volumes from the AWS Powershell utilities.  The instance would be created, and then terminate immediately with an InstanceInitiatedShutdown. I was eventually able to solve the issue by explicitly defining a "gp2" volume, and setting it to devicename `'/dev/sda1'` in a block device mapping.  You may have to likewise investigate and modify your root volume.

Comment: Thanks @HyperAnthony. I'm not sure I have the skills for that and may do more damage than good. :P  I found this though ["There is no easy way of changing the vitalization type from PV to HVM... Your best solution would be to spin up a new instance and migrate your data."](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=558479)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676933/migrate-from-t1-micro-to-t2-micro-amazon-aws

Answer (score 6):

I was going from HVM to PV and noticing the same issue. It turned out that I (my automation) was still attaching block storage to /dev/sda1, what I needed for my HVM AMI, but needed to attached it to /dev/xvda.

Comment: For me the same thing happens on an LC. For some reason AWS doesn't match mount with AMI when it validates the LC.

Comment: I had the same issue on a HVM instance (latest HVM Amazon Linux kernel 5.10) ami-0f9fc25dd2506cf6d.  Had to switch from `sda1` to `xvda`, which was easy enough to verify by manually launching and checking the volume device in the console.